# Java retrieving array and printing it in a for each loop

Tags: java, arrays, foreach

I am trying to make a program where it retrieves a set of arrays from a different class

```
int barHeights[] = new int[]
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
```

then calling it in a method and printing it out

```
public void init(int[] barHeights)
{
    Bar[] barArray = new Bar[barHeights.length];
    for (Bar bar : barArray){
        System.out.println(bar);
}
```

i'm unsure why it is printing out 'null' 7 times in a row in the console. Shouldn't it be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Comment: No, you don't do anything to move the data from `barHeights` to `barArray`.  All you do is look at the length of `barHeights`, not the data.  Also, what's a `Bar`, and why do you think a `Bar` is a kind of integer?

Comment: How would I pull the data then? Bar is a name I gave because i have other classes that are Block etc

Comment: You are also using barHeights when the variable is barheights

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In line:

```
Bar[] barArray = new Bar[barHeights.length];
```

You are creating an instance of array of Bar class references instead of int. 
This array is automaticly initialized with null values, and in line:

```
for (Bar bar : barArray){
    System.out.println(bar);
```

You are interating those null values.
If you want to retrive the array, which you passed as an argument to method, you should use:

```
public void init(int[] barHeights) {
    for (int i : barHeights) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have created arry Bar but not initialized it, so it is initialized with null.

```
Bar[] barArray = new Bar[barHeights.length];
```

when you loop through barArray

```
for (Bar bar : barArray){
    System.out.println(bar);
```

it will display null.

Comment: How should I go around in initializing it?

Comment: @Heroge Since you haven't told us anything about the `Bar` class, how can we possibly answer that question?

Comment: @Heroge we conld't tell you about initialization of Bar class , because you don't give us enough information.

Answer (score 0):

Code should be like this.

```
class Bar {
    private int height;

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
}
```

Algorithm should be like this

1.create another array type of Bar named barArray.

2.loop height array named barHeights

3.within loop create new object of Bar for each round

4.set height for each object

5.add bar object to array

```
public void init(int[] barHeights)
{
    Bar[] barArray = new Bar[barHeights.length];
    int index=0;
    for (int height : barHeights){
        Bar bar=new Bar();
        bar.setHeight(height);
        barArray[index]=bar;
        index++;
        System.out.println(bar);
    }
}
```